# is a good approach defining 2 useEffect Hooks, see my use of case bellow

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I tried to find the same case, but everyone is in a different situation.

I've created 2 useEffects in my component, one for initializing the component (1 execution) and another to fetch data when some state (filter) changes. (many executions)

```
const [filter1, setFilter1] = useState({});
const [filter2, setFilter2] = useState({});

//initialize filters, only once
useEffect(() => {
  //here i fetch all the data to fill the filter components.
  setFilter1(data1); 
  setFilter2(data2);
}, []);
//everytime my filters change.
useEffect(() => {
  //here i fetch data using the filter as parameters.
}, [filter1,filter2]);
```

The code above is my last approach and works fine. Every time I change the filters the useEffect fetch the data and load the table with that data.

I show below the old approach that I took, and the one I didn't like.

```
const loadData = useCallback((filter1,filter2) => {
   //here i fetch data using the filter as parameters.
   }, [filter1,filter2]);

 useEffect(() => {
   //here i fetch all the data to fill the filter components.
    setFilter1(data1); 
    setFilter2(data2);
    loadData(filter1, filter2);
  },[]);
```

and I used the loadData function in every filter change handler like:

```
  const onFilter1Change = (val) => {
     setFilter1(val);
     loadData(val, filter2)
  };
```

The old approach above brought me some issues regarding how to use the hooks properly and that's why I find myself asking you React experts, how to improve my coding in the best way.

The new approach works fine for me, tho I wonder if it's right to use 2 useEffect in this case, or if there is a better way to do it.

Cheers

Comment: Is the second `useEffect` hook with `filter1` and `filter2` as dependencies, what is it ultimately doing? Overall it seems a sound, logical implementation. Depending on what each hook actually does only then can we provide more insight.

Comment: @DrewReese the second useEffect fetches data from an API, that later I use to display in a table. So the first one load the filters and the second get executed every time a filter is changed in order to load the table with data.

Comment: Then I don't see any overt issue with the implementation.

Comment: @DrewReese Ok thanks for your help. It's my first time using Hooks, so I want to read from a different point of view.

Answer (score 0):

Where `data1` & `data2` comes from?
If it's a prop, and you are using a `useEffect` only to initialize them, you don't need a `useEffect` for that:

```js
const [filter1, setFilter1] = useState(data1);
const [filter2, setFilter2] = useState(data2);

useEffect(() => {
  //here i fetch data using the filter as parameters.
}, [filter1, filter2]);
```

Comment: I interpreted `//here i fetch all the data to fill the filter components.` for the origin of `data1` and `data2`.

Comment: @dbuchet data1 and data2 is the data that comes from the API that I fetched in order to initially load my filters.

Comment: Oh ok sorry, so I don"t think there is any issue with the code you provide :) Maybe just check if `filter1` & `filter2` are set in your second `useEffect` before fetching anything there